# Validation of webjobs running or not through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I want to check whether the all the continuous and triggered webjobs are running or not after the webjobs start.Please help me.Through powershell script how to validate.

Currently I am deploying the webapp through VSTS to Azure app service using app service deploy plugin and after that I am starting the webjobs using powershell script.So after starting the webjobs,I need to cross check whether the webjobs (Continuous and triggered ) are properly started or not.This is my actual question.Kindly help me how to write script to validate the webjobs running or not.

The below code to start the web jobs after webapp deploy.

```
[object]$paramObj=Get-Content "d:\a\r1\a\WebJobs\drop\Parameter.json" |ConvertFrom-Json 
    $userName =$paramObj.userName 
    $password =$paramObj.password
    $webAppName =$paramObj.webAppName
    $resourceGroup=$paramObj.resourceGroup
    [object[]]$webJobs=$paramObj.webJobs
    foreach($wj in $webjobs){
     if($wj.typeName -eq "continuous")
     {
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName "$webAppName/$($wj.name)" -Action start -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
      Write-Host "continuous"
     Write-Host $wj.name
     }
     else{
     Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/TriggeredWebJobs -ResourceName "$webAppName/$($wj.name)" -Action run -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -force
     Write-Host "triggered"
     Write-Host $wj.name
     }
     }
```

and I am passing parameter.json file to pass parameters to the above script.after running the above script how to validate.I need that script.

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Get-AzureRmResource to get web job status. You could try following script.

```
$ResourceGroupName="****"
$AppService="****"
$Apiversion="2016-08-01"
$continuejob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
$continuejob.Properties.status

$triggerjob=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/TriggeredWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
$triggerjob.Properties.latest_run
```

Comment: Great answer.Thanks for your help.I am getting the status but suppose if any continuous or triggered job is not running then I need to run again those jobs after running the above script which you shared.How to write script for this and how to include that script in the above script? Any condition does I need to implement ? If yes, Please share me the script.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN It depends on your demand. If your job is not running, maybe you need write a loop wait for a moment and check again.

Comment: Can I have the script to check for a moment ? and if my any triggered or continuous job is not running then I need to start again .So how to write the script  in which above scripts includes? Please help me.

Comment: ok Thanks.I will ask a new question.Please help me out.

Comment: oh No issues.I will wait for your help.By the way what's is your country name?

Comment: I will let you know by tomorrow. Thanks much. I yet to test the code.

Comment: This worked for me (for a continuous webjob at least) but I needed to change the command to `Get-AzResource` as an FYI to devs 6y in the future